# Check if a client is connected to the OwnCloud server

Tags: shell, command-line, owncloud

How one could check on the server where `ownloud` is running if currently a client is connected? Is there a command provided by `ownloud` itself or can this be done via `Bash`?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, yet! You can make an plugin which looks up the last sync time.
And if `$time < 60 secs ago` then client is online.